# Laravel Pagination render method does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jquery-jscroll

I'm trying to get the infinite loading / lazy loading working and below is my code.

**Controller**

```
$categories = Category::with(['products' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('status', StatusConstant::PT_ACTIVE)->paginate(20);
                    $query->with(['purchased' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('user_id', $this->user->id);
                    }])->paginate(20);
                }])->get();
```

**View**

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <div id="tabs{{ $category->id }}" class="col s12">
        <div class="contents-tabs">
            @if (isset($category->products))
                <div class="infinite-scroll">
                    @forelse($category->products as $record)
                    <div class="cart-product first">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s4">
                                <div class="contents">
                                    <img src='{{ asset("/storage/uploads/$record->cover") }}' alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @empty
                    <div class="cart-product first">
                        <div class="row">
                            <p class="promo">Null</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforelse
                    {!! $category->products->render() !!}
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

**Js**

```
$(function() {
        $('.infinite-scroll').jscroll({
            autoTrigger: true,
            loadingHtml: '<img class="center-block" src="{{ asset('images/loading.gif') }}" alt="Loading..." />',
            padding: 0,
            nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
            contentSelector: 'div.infinite-scroll',
            callback: function() {
                $('ul.pagination').remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

**Error**

> [2019-05-08 16:41:37] production.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::render does not exist.

Comment: I don't think putting presentation logic in the `with` would work. Maybe you need to rethink this

Comment: @apokryfos yea... i couldn't find solution for this, and the term "with" is tricky

Comment: Instead of using the relationship you could create a custom query with the Query Builder for this to work.

Comment: @Dan could you please give me some example for this? Appreciate it!! Thanks

Comment: If i need to load all the categories, and having the pagination for each categories. I'm out of idea

Comment: Paginate the products for each category in a separate controller method e.g. `categories/{category}/products`. Start the page without any products and load the first page asynchronously. Not sure how to setup jquery-scroll to work with this though

Comment: try to dd the $categories  variable and it need to give length aware paginator instance

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about this, I don't see a good use-case for jScroll here. To my understanding, it's supposed to get used once on the page and load new elements once you're close to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Dan yea, jscroll doesn't affecting the render, it's actually working based on the Laravael pagination

Comment: @Manojkiran.A Please check updated question, supposed to have a paginator variable?

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for the idea, if this is not working then will consider for altenative as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Because the method really [does not exists](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) :)

`$categories` is an object of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`, because of your `->paginate(10)` at the end of the chain:

```php
$query->with(['purchased' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', $this->user->id);
}])->paginate(10);
   //^ here
```

`$category->products` is an object of [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html).

You have to paginate `products` before calling `render()`.

Try `$category->products()->paginate(10)->render()` inside blade view or

```php
$categories = Category::with(['products' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('status', StatusConstant::PT_ACTIVE)->paginate(10);
                                                                      //^
                    $query->with(['purchased' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('user_id', $this->user->id);
                    }])->paginate(10);
                }])->get();
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

Comment: I've tried all your edit and no luck :'( [2019-05-08 17:36:31] production.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist. (View:

Comment: Can you `dd($category->products)`? What's in the output? @1myb

Comment: You goal is to make `$category->products` paginated before you call `render()`

Comment: Consider to have enough `product` to paginate https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19421

Comment: Please check the updated question. I have 200 dummy products in the db.

Comment: @1myb have you tried `$category->products()->paginate(10)->render()`?

Comment: Yep, and this is the error: 2019-05-08 17:52:55] production.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist. (View:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193021/discussion-between-1myb-and-tarasovych).